# Remove standard file manager

Tags: pantheon-files, files

How do I remove the standard "files" application in elementary? I already set the new file manager (Polo) as the new default, via the settings. I checked if that worked via `xdg-mime query default inode/directory` and it shows me that this worked. All that's left to do know is getting rid of the old file manager.

I found out that I can run pantheon via this command: `io.elementary.files` but there is no package with this name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohh I found it the package name is just `pantheon-files` :)